# How to mock a ProducerScope from callbackFlow builder in Kotlin Flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockk, kotlin-flow

I'd like to test a function where I use the scope of a [`callbackFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) builder. Assuming I have a function inside the flow builder like this:

```
fun items(): Flow<Items> = callbackFlow {
    getItems(this) {
        trySend(it)
    }
    awaitClose()
}
```

In `getItems` function, I received data from websockets. The scope of ProducerScope is used to either `launch` a new coroutine with a delay and do something or to `close` the scope if an error happens. So it might call `scope.launch { }` or `scope.close()`.

For example, this could do something as follows:

```
fun getItems(scope: ProducerScope<Items>, callback: (Items) -> Unit) {
    if (something) {
        scope.launch { ... }
    }
    if (somethingElse) {
        ...
        scope.close(error)
    }
    ...
    callback(items)
}
```

The callbackFlow's block uses a [`ProducerScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-producer-scope/index.html), extension of `CoroutineScope` and `SendChannel`, I tried to mock it using [Mockk](https://mockk.io):

```
val scope: ProducerScope<Items> = mockk()
```

Unfortunately, I end up with:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext$Element$Subclass6 cannot be cast to class kotlin.coroutines.ContinuationInterceptor

How can I mock a `ProducerScope`?
How do I unit test `getItems` above when `scope` can be either a CoroutineScope and a SendChannel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your primary question is "How to mock a `ProducerScope` ?" I think you might be out of luck. Mocking internal coroutine components is not easy and generally not a good idea. For example, a mocked `ProducerScope` will never call the `awaitClose` callback, and therefor break cancellation behavior.
If you want to, you can add details about the implemetation of `getItems` to get a proper solution.

Comment: Good point @AdrianK for `awaitClose` but I thought to mock it with a fake ProducerScope... Anyway, I added some context in my question. The main thing here is the trigger of `launch` and `close` in `getItems`. That causes the raise of the exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I cannot do this easily without expecting strange behaviors. So I refactored my function to use a `Channel` and a `CoroutineScope` separately. Thanks to [the CoroutineScope `plus` extension](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/plus.html), I can create a new scope from the flow builder. This is now testable!

Therefore, the flow builder became:

```
fun items(): Flow<Items> = callbackFlow {
    val channel = this.channel
    val scope = this.plus(this.coroutineContext)

    getItems(channel, scope) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My function still uses both but gets them separately:

```
fun getItems(
    channel: SendChannel<Items>, 
    scope: CoroutineScope, 
    callback: (Items) -> Unit
) {
    if (something) {
        scope.launch { ... } // <-- use scope
    }
    if (somethingElse) {
        ...
        channel.close(error) // <-- use channel
    }
    ...
    callback(items)
}
```

Then, I can now test using a `Channel` with the same requirements than the one in `callbackFlow` and the scope from `runTest`:

```
@Test
fun `get items and succeed`() = runTest {
    val channel = Channel<Any>(Channel.BUFFERED, BufferOverflow.SUSPEND)
    ...

    service.getItems(channel, this@runTest, callback)
    ...
}
```